# Kubernetes V1DeleteOptions useless for namespace delete?

Tags: kubernetes

Seems like **V1DeleteOptions** in **Kubernetes** namespace delete API is useless.

For example,

- I created a service in a namespace. Later on, I tried to delete the
  namespace and setting **V1DeleteOptions**.propagationPolicy to false.
- But turns out the namespace and the service are both deleted
  immediately.
- I also tried setting V1DeleteOptions.GracePeriodSeconds to 100 just
  to test the grace period. But still, the namespace and the service
  are deleted immediately.

So, does the V1DeleteOptions in Kubernetes namespace delete API do anything at all?

Comment: Which client are you using? did you try to put the V1DeleteOptions in the body?

Answer (score 0):

look like this flag is used for 'how garbage collection will be performed'

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/client-python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1DeleteOptions.md

Note:
when we delete the namespace, it should cleanup the all object inside the name. I think delete command worked properly.